# SQL query considering two tables

Tags: sql

There is a table called **xengallery_album_permissions** with columns: `album_id int(10)`, `permission enum ('view', 'add')`, `access_type enum('public', 'followed', 'members', 'private', 'shared')`

There is another table called **xengallery_album** with columns: `album_id int(10)`, `album_state enum('visible', 'moderated', 'deleted')`

Right now I have the following query:

```
SELECT `album_id`
FROM `xengallery_album_permission`
WHERE `permission` = "view" AND `access_type` != "public"
```

But I want to filter the results and only list `album_id` that have `album_state = visible`

How can I modify my query to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT p.album_id
FROM `xengallery_album_permission` p
INNER JOIN xengallery_album a ON a.album_id = p.album_id
WHERE p.permission = "view" 
  AND p.access_type != "public"
  AND a.album_state  = "visible"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT a.album_id
FROM xengallery_album_permission a
inner join xengallery_album b
on a.album_id == b.album_id
WHERE a.permission = "view" AND a.access_type != "public"
and b.album_state = "visible"
```

Here is a short tutorial on [Inner Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [Alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)